# How to use Piler with standard HTML instead of Jade?

Tags: html, node.js, pug, piler

I am using Node.js with Piler (https://github.com/epeli/piler).
The example at the project website shows how to use Piler with an index.jade file.

index.jade:

```
!!! 5
html
  head
    !{css}
    !{js}
  body
    h1 Hello Piler
```

The `!{css}` and `!{js}` tags will translate to the corresponding html tags when the index file gets delivered to the client.

For example : `<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>`

How can I use Piler without an index.jade file but instead with an index.html file?
What are the `!{css}` and `!{js}` tags supposed to look like in the index.html?

With other words: I don't want to use Piler with Jade but instead with standard html.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Piler by default stores concat versions of the js and css in the piler cache directory which you can specify by passing the `outputDirectory` parameter when creating your JS/CSS Manager.

```
pilerCachePath = '/www/your-project/public-path/assets/';
var clientjs = piler.createJSManager({outputDirectory: pilerCachePath});
var clientcss = piler.createCSSManager({outputDirectory: pilerCachePath});
```

You can define a public path that you can access and then in your html, just use these paths

```
<!-- ... -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/global.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- ... -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/global.js"></script>
</body>
```

However, i would recommend to use [gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com/) for that purpose. Their documentation has a [very good introduction](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) on how to use it.